# Append image header to nearest overlay span

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append the `<h3>` header to each of the `et_overlay` spans on a page. Here is an example:-

```
<li class="product">
    <a href="https://foo.com/product/foo">
        <span class="et_shop_image">
            <img width="400" height="400" src="https://foo.com/wp-content/uploads/foo.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog" alt="Alt text" title="Product Title">
            <span class="et_overlay"></span>
        </span>
        <h3>Product Title Goes here</h3>
    </a>
</li>
```

The jQuery I'm using is:-

```
  /*Add product on-hover information*/
  $("li.product h3").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest("span.et_overlay").append($this.clone());
  });
```

I get the feeling I'm close, but the `<h3>` text isn't appending as specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$("li.product").each(function(i,e) {
    $(e).find(".et_overlay").append($(e).find('h3').clone());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `.closest()` in `$this.closest("span.et_overlay").append($this.clone());` as `.closest()` traverses UP the DOM and `"span.et_overlay"` isn't an ancestor. Instead use:

```
$this.prev('span.et_shop_image').find("span.et_overlay").append($this.clone());
```

```js
$("li.product h3").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prev('span.et_shop_image').find("span.et_overlay").append($this.clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="product">
    <a href="https://foo.com/product/foo">
      <span class="et_shop_image">
            <img width="400" height="400" src="https://foo.com/wp-content/uploads/foo.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog" alt="Alt text" title="Product Title">
            <span class="et_overlay"></span>
      </span>
      <h3>Product Title Goes here</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```